# How to pass selected class properties to sql table using Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an empty sql table which contains around 100 column headers (fields), using database first approach I have created a single class with all the 100 fields as properties. Now I want to select only 10 fields out of all the properties and insert some data to those fields, such that the existing table should have the inserted data for only those 10 columns and the remaining columns should be updated with NULL. For instance,

```
public class Product
{
public int UniqueID {get; set;}
public string ProductName {get; set;}
public string type {get; set;}
etc......
}
```

Now I want the table should be updated with only UniqueID and ProductName and all the remaining fields should have NULL.
I am thinking of using `Dictionary<string,object>`, to add all the selected properties to dictionary and pass it to the database table.
Please share some ideas on how to implement this scenario using Entity Framework.

Comment: You can reflect and hydrate properties to an instance, then add I think

Answer (score 1):

If it is MVC and you want to add/edit a subset use a [view model](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2013/03/Why-You-Never-Expose-Your-Domain-Model-As-Your-MVC-Model/):

```
// this is a viewmodel intended for a particular view, for example AddProductSubset.chtml
public class AddProductSubsetViewModel
{
    public int UniqueID {get; set;}
    public string ProductName {get; set;}
    // add other properties you will be updating from the entity model
    // you can also add properties from other entities or things only needed by the view
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddProductSubset(AddProductSubsetViewModel vm)
{
    var vm = new AddProductSubsetViewModel();
    // fill in any default values before add/edit
    return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProductSubset(AddProductSubsetViewModel vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // map your viewmodel to the entity model. See automapper.
        var product = new Product 
        {
            UniqueID = vm.UniqueID,   // unless this is identity, then omit
            ProductName = vm.ProductName,
            otherfield = vm.otherfield,
            ...
            // unmapped entity fields will be set to their default (null, etc)
        }
        context.Products.Add(product);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index")
    }
    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve. I tried the above option, this displayed all the class properties in the View. However my requirement is to display only the properties which I passed in product variable and hide the remaining properties in the view.

Comment: You're not getting it - this is a very common scenario. Put the properties you want to display in the viewmodel and on the POST transfer them back to the entity and save. Why would you use reflection for something so simple?

Answer (score 0):

You can reflect and hydrate properties to an instance, then add I think. This should do it

```
public void ReflectIntoModel<T>(Dictionary<string, object> dic)
        {
            T m = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
            var prop = typeof(T).GetProperties();

            foreach (var a in prop)
            {
                dynamic val;
                if (dic.TryGetValue(a.Name, out val))
                    a.SetValue(m, val);
            }
        }
```

Just make sure you're careful with typing the value, and the fact that the field names are case sensitive

Comment: Thank you Sameer. But I am quite new to asp.net, could you please explain in detail as in how to use the above option in mvc.

Comment: sure thing. Once you've added the necessary values to your dictionary, for using EF you should of course have a class inheriting from DbContext (say ProductContext) which implements a DbSet property which represents your table 

DbSet<Product> Products {get; set;}

you just need to 

yourProductContext.Products.Add(ReflectIntoModel<Product>(***Pass the Dictionary<string,object> here***));
yourProductContext.SaveChanges();

Comment: Part 1. Having read your comment on the question below, I realized what you were looking for wasn't pointing towards "class properties to sql table using Dictionary", rather getting a dictionary of fields rendered and inserted into the DB. Well, the most elegant way of doing this is to create a ViewModel then translate it into the entity Product, then persist. But if you are insistent on having a dynamic ViewModel based on a Dictionary, its not impossible either.

What is to keep in mind here is that we're talking about generic text based input fields here.

Comment: Hi Sameer, I tried the above option, but getting an error "cannot convert from 'void' to 'SampleProject.Product'                                                                   Dictionary<string, object> item = new Dictionary<string, object> { {"UniqueID",101},{"ProductName", "Ford"},{"Color","Black"}};  db.products.add(ReflectIntoModel<Product>(item));  db.SaveChanges();

Comment: Well, I already have a class generated from the sql table which has all the properties of Product class, out of which I just wanted to select few properties, display them in view and update those fields in existing sql table and the remaining fields to be NULL

Comment: Part 2. Create a Dictionary of fields you would want to persist, and put them in the ViewBag. In the View, create a container form with the appropriate route. Then inside it, loop through each of the items in the dictionary making sure you set the name attribute of the input field to the name of key in the dictionary. Mark up an HttpPost Action on the controller you want. When the postback comes in create a dictionary out of the values you receive in the Request.Form. Here is the tricky bit. You have to make sure to get the conversions right which can be achieved by a snippet

Comment: Part 3.

public T ReflectIntoModel<T>(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection dic)
        {
            T m = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
            var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();

            foreach (var key in dic.AllKeys)
            {
                var currProp = props.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.ToLower() == key.ToLower());
                if (currProp != null)
                {
                    var val = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(currProp.PropertyType).ConvertFromString(dic[key]);

Comment: Part 4. 

currProp.SetValue(m, val);
                }
            }

            return m;
        }


You should just be able to pass Request.Form in this snippet and it should convert the necessary properties for you to give you your entity, which you can persist easily

Comment: Thank you very much Sameer.. That helps :)